# How to do partial history search without sticky matching

Tags: bash, bashrc

If I put this in my .bashrc:

```
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'
```

It mostly works, but if I go up and don't like the match, I can't go back down and get back what I typed.  For example, if my history is:

```
xyz
123
abcd
```

and I type "abc" with up arrow, it will find "abcd".  But if I down arrow from there, "abcd" is stuck there. I want it to do like ipython and go back to "abc".  Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't moved your cursor, `Ctrl-K` will bring you to the "original" command, as it deletes everything after the cursor.

There's no reasonable way to map this to the down key, as far as I know. The plus here is you can hit `Ctrl-K` at any point while in your  search history, not just the most recent item.